# In pyspark, How to filter rows where a list column has at least one element which starts with a substring?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe in the below structure

| Name | IRC_List |
| --- | --- |
| A | `[LLL,V23,VLX]` |
| B | `[LSS,LX3,LLX]` |
| C | `[LSS,L12,VLX]` |

After filtering the table should be:

| Name | IRC_List |
| --- | --- |
| A | `[LLL,V23,VLX]` |
| C | `[LSS,L12,VLX]` |

B should be filtered out since the corresponding list does not have any element starting with "V".

For reference, I am using Spark 2.3.0

Comment: Pls post schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a dynamic approach with parameter and own data, not v2.3 I see:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

param = "V"
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [( 1, ["Vapple", "Kpear"],), (2, ["plan", "pipeV"],), (3, ["cat", "Vant"],)], ["key", "value_string_array"]
)

filter_starts_with = lambda s: s.startswith(param)
df.filter(exists(col("value_string_array"), filter_starts_with)).show()
```

You will have to roll your own for v2.3.